# How to have unique Featured Links for each page?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to have featured links on the sidebar for each page. Each page will have unique featured links.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 ways, I think:
1. Most simple one - use Custom Fields feature, and add a custom field with a structure pretty much like this:

```
http://google.com|Google Site
http://some-other-site.com|Other link text
```

You can parse such a format pretty easily.

1. Use custom fields and add a meta box to post editor page to provide usable editor interface - that will take pretty much time...
2. Create a table that will have page_id, link_url, link_text fields and select from it dynamically. I suppose it is not the best way though.